# Securely allow SSH from Parallels to Host MacOS w/o risking Network threats?

Tags: network, security, ssh, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I want to enable SSH on OSX from only my Parallels VM.  My fear is that by opening SSH I'm putting my host OS at risk for remote exploitation.

> How can I configure MacOS to only allow connections from the local Parallels' Windows machine?

Perhaps I can establish a dedicated VNet for the two machines, but I'm not sure how to restrict MacOS to listen only that subnet / IP address.

Comment: If you already have SSH running, how are you "opening it more broadly" if you are connecting from a VM on that machine?  Assuming you're using a bridged network, it's just another node on the same subnet.  If you're using host only, then it will only connect the VM and host.

Comment: @allan Regardless of the parallels configuration, MacOS SSH will listen on all subnets and virtual machines. Ideally I want to restrict by both interface and source IP. Both will remain static on localhost

Comment: I understand how SSH works on a Mac.  I am trying to understand what you want to do in the context you described.  So, what I am understand from your comment is that you want to ***lock down*** SSH so it communicates only between the VM and the host.  Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set the parameter "ListenAddresss" to only the IP-address your host Mac has on the dedicated VNet you have create between the host and the virtual machine (host-only networking).

Remember to remove:

```
  ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
  ListenAddress ::
```

and replace it with just:

```
  ListenAddress 176.16.236.111
```

(where 176.16.236.111 should be replaced with whatever your IP-address is on that private network)